# C# TabPage не отрисовывается изображение

Tags: c#, winforms

В конструкторе формы добавил ImageList и в него добавил изображение.
На вкладке выбрал изображение в ImageIndex.
В конструкторе формы изображения показывается, все ок:

[image: Imgur]

А в runtime изображения нет, хотя вкладка растянулась:

[image: Imgur]

В коде нигде не затрагивается ImageList или ImageIndex.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: проверьте, что файл изображения копируется в конечную папку при сборке проекта если он не интегрирован в ресурсы

Comment: Попробуйте, ничего не делая в конструкторе, с помощью одного только дизайнера форм, привязать  ImageList к Вашему tabControl (property ImageList) и после этого для каждой из закладок выберите конструктором форм из списка ImageList для свойства ImageKey нужную картинку. После этого у Вас все заработает.